# An indefinite article before 'boys' in 'Man thinks about a little bit of baby girls and a baby boys'

Tags: articles

There's a line in James Brown's song 'It's A Man's, Man's, Man's World' puzzling me. It goes : 'Man thinks about a little bit of baby girls and a baby boys' - why is there an indefinite article before "baby boys" ? Thank you from a non-native speaker.

Comment: I think it's probably not an indefinite article. It might be a mis-transcribed version of "of".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic. It does not appear to be about English language and usage within the scope defined in the help center. Lyrics famously often show scant regard for standard English. And it's not even certain that the transcription here is correct.

Comment: @sumelic That sounds like a good possibility. Another is the singer chose to slur his speech at that point.  Like a child saying "bowl uh candy" rather than "bowl of candy". Or maybe it was a vocalized riff he made at that point in the song, which was not even meant to be interpreted as a word. "of baby girls and baby boys" makes perfect sense on its own. In any case, we both think he did not actually mean "a baby boys".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth instead of closing it, would it not be better housed at English Language Learners? As far as Kate knew, the mysterious **a** was normative, and she was asking why.  You were right, as my answer shows, that the transcription was incorrect. With the facts she had, though, it seemed like an English-related question.

Comment: I'm very grateful for all your answers.
...And extremely sorry for asking the question in the wrong place; I was pondering on whether to post it in English Language Learners or here and settled on, well, 'here' for some reason. Perhaps I should have thought more about where to put it.
I did check Google Play Music, but I also found a lot of sources with the questionable 'a' in the lyrics, so I decided to ask anyway just to be certain that it's not a special meaning too tricky for me to grasp.

Comment: They don't appreciate poor questions over there either. This is an inappropriate question on any site devoted to how the English language is actually used – it is inaccurate.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm truly sorry for the trouble. Now I see why it was inappropriate to ask. It's difficult to be absolutely confident that something is a simple mistranscription when you still have a lot to learn about the language.

Comment: Sorry, Kate; the second comment should have been addressed to RichF. // You do need to make sure quotes are accurate. /  ELL, our sister site, is probably more appropriate for the vast majority of questions learners have.

Comment: (referring both to the comment you meant to direct at me and your comment directly above this) How can ELL be an "English learners" site if we make people afraid to ask questions they think are about English?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Google Play Music [transcribes the line](https://play.google.com/music/preview/Tcqur6vowf7s3xf375zlm7zatbi?lyrics=1&utm_source=google&utm_medium=search&utm_campaign=lyrics&pcampaignid=kp-songlyrics) as follows:

> Man thinks about our little bitty baby girls and our baby boys

In this version, there is no article at all.  Instead it is the word **our** instead of the **a** used in the questioner's transcription.

Comment: Surely the lyrics appeared in written form direct from the source; they wouldn't need to be transcribed.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You are correct.  I revisited the Google Play lyrics page, and it contains a copyright notice at the bottom. That is a very likely indication of it being authoritative.

Comment: So _Google Play Music_ just quote/s the lyrics.